# Grammar check on a sentence with one subject, many verbs in sequence, and no conjunctions between them

Tags: american-english, sentence, writing-style

Here is a sentence from my article. Just wondering if there is anything wrong with having sentences which are too long.

> He created some data, put up some samples, initiated a sequence and finally, set up a Demo.

I mean, the usage of too many commas in a single sentence.

Comment: The number of words or the number of commas is not limited by any grammatical or stylistic rules *per se*, as long as the sentence as a whole is cohesive, meaningful, understandable and unambiguous. You may include a comma after *sequence* if your style manual allows the Oxford Comma.

Comment: Three commas is too many? You will easily find sentences with thirty. Seventeen words is too long? You will easily find sentences with 170.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no upper limit to the number of commas or words that can go into a sentence. Whether your individual sentence is too long depends entirely on whether your readers will be able to understand and fully comprehend its meaning.

> He created some data, put up some samples, initiated a sequence and finally, set up a Demo.

This sentence is fine with the possible fix that you should put another comma before "finally":

> He created some data, put up some samples, initiated a sequence and, finally, set up a Demo.

Unless he has been meaning to set up a Demo for ages and finally got around to it. Then you should remove the comma *after* finally:

> He created some data, put up some samples, initiated a sequence and finally set up a Demo.

Answer (score -2):

There are at least two problems with the sentence:

1. The last comma should be placed after the word *sequence* rather than after *finally*.
2. Why is *demo* capitalized? It should be lowercase.

Stylistically, its also a poor sentence for at least three reasons:

1. *created some data* is odd. First, it seems that one **compiles** data or some other verb.
2. *put up some samples* is a very odd utterance as well.
3. The repetition of *some* is odd.

Comment: The comma after *finally* is fine. *Demo* is capitalized because it is the name of the program version. The sentence is 'stylistically' acceptable, except for a preferable 'Oxford' comma after *sequence*.

Comment: @Kris, I don't believe *Demo is capitalized because it is the name of the program version.* We don't have any such information from the asker. I don't think the sentence is stylistically acceptable and I'd like to see a cite for the claim you can put the comma after "finally"

Comment: purely prescriptive.

Comment: I’d say if there is to be a comma after ‘finally’, there should be one before it as well.

Comment: @virmaior, there is nothing strange about creating data. If we are talking about an application/website/similar where you are making a mockup or demo, the first thing you do is exactly to populate your database with some data that you yourself create. In this context, it makes sense.

Comment: @virmaior The comma after *finally* is fine because *finally* is parenthetical.

Comment: The comments were getting a bit confusing, what with a simple typo that was subsequently deleted, so I've cleaned them up and deleted the ones that no longer apply.